# babel + path + node 6.x: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I've been trying to update my nodejs version to 6.x but the following errors always appear everytime:

```
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1326:5)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:374:36
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:396:22
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:385:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:369:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328:14)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:370:14
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:390:24
```

I tried with those three version:

- nodejs-6.0.0-1
- nodejs-6.2.0-1
- nodejs-6.2.1-1

in `package.json`:
`"babel-core": "^6.9.1"`

I quite lost about where to start looking to debug. Anybody has a suggestion ? :) More info would be relevent ? Let me know !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you cleared node_modules and reinstalled to ensure you are fully updated?

Comment: Ah ! I missed your comment ! Yes, I tried reinstalling, but no luck...

Comment: Given that the error is `/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-core`, it doesn't even look like the version of `babel-core` in use is the one inside your module, it's a global version for some reason. We don't recommend installing Babel globally, so I'd `npm uninstall -g babel-core babel-cli` and any other Babel modules you have as global modules, then make sure your build script is properly using your direct module dependency.

Comment: Oh, I would never have noticed that it was the global module. Thank you so much, you solved my problem. I thought it would be more complicated haha. I'll keep in mind to make sure I'm using project dependencies for the future !

Answer (score 5):

The issue has something to do with Node 6. Using Node 5.x instead will probably fix the issue for you, if that's an option.

The easiest way to do this is to [install Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) ([or a port for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)), then run these commands:

```
nvm install 5
nvm use 5
```

If you want to use 5.x as your default node version, run this command:

```
nvm alias default 5
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution namuol. Babel-node seem to have a version that works with node 6 though. loganfsmyth made me notice that I was using a global module and I was not updating those so just installing the last version made it work. With the last version of bael-node, everything works just fine :)

Comment: @vsync I strongly encourage you to use NVM -- it makes this sort of thing so much easier! The install script makes it pretty easy to install: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script

Comment: @namuol - I don't have a Mac , don't know how to use one, and don't wish to know :) NVM is not for windows. therefor your answer is inadequate for half the global population..

Comment: @vsync If you're using Windows, there's a Windows-specific (non-bash) version of NVM: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

I assure you that developers of open source software aren't trying to make your life harder. :) I'll update my answer to link to NVM for Windows!

Comment: but I don't want to install NVM for windows.. if I want to install some version of Node, I simply download the installer from Node's website and double-click and there you have it. the magic of using windows :)

Answer (score 5):

upgrade babel-core to 6.10.4..

Comment: Though uninstalling global packages is the solution to this question, upgrade all babel packages solved my problem.